# Research input-text for mysql query, php coding

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i have a problem about coding a php page, where i can see a table (a mysql table) but i have to filter this table when i insert username, id_user, email or address (for example). I'll copy the code that i wrote for a single field:

```
if (!isset($_GET['name']))
     $query = "not interesting";
else if($_GET['name'] != ''){
     $var145 = $_GET['name'];
     $query = "not interesting where `Name` = '$var145'";
}
else 
     $query = "not interesting";
```

This work very well, because when the form is not sent, it will display all the table, when the text is not null it will display the query with the filter and when the text is null it will display all the table. Do you know how to help me? I don't know how to improve three more input text to research better records because i have to check the existance of the variables and then decide what to do. Sorry for my bad english, i hope you understood my problem. Thanks to everyone

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement complex filtering. Typically this is done by building a "WHERE" clause as you process each form field, instead of making the whole query based on each field. Also, please read the docs about SQL Injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Sorry but now i  can't read it. My last chance for this complex filtering is to submit the form only one time. Do you know something usefull about this? I know there is a function, but it will cause a loop if we can't block it, because the page will be reload and the script will be execute again and again

Comment: That -1... why?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! It's not the best code that I can imagine, but i post it hoping that it will be usefull for someone

```
$doc1_queryI = "SELECT * from t_history";
$var1 = 0;  //a
$var2 = 1;  //b
$var3 = 1;  //c
$var4 = 0;  //d
$varAnd =0;
if($var1==1 or $var2==1 or $var3==1 or $var4==1)
   $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryI." where"; //se almeno una session esiste
if($var1==1){
   $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." x=a ";
   $varAnd =1;
}
if($var2==1)
{
    if($varAnd==1)
       $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." and ";
    $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." y=b ";
    else
       $varAnd =1;
}
if($var3==1)
{
    if($varAnd==1)
        $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." and ";
    $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." z=c ";
    else
   $varAnd =1;
}
if($var4==1)
{
    if($varAnd==1)
        $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." and ";
    $doc1_queryF = $doc1_queryF." p=d ";
}
echo $doc1_queryF;`
```